# save data in model class, load in viewController, init method, NSCoder, NSArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, init

I am newbie to Xcode please help.

I have three viewControllers (Sub class `UIViewController`) and one Model class(Sub class `NSObject`).
When app launch it -->"ViewController.h" loads and then navigates to
--> "DetailsViewController.h" --> "AddHoursViewController.h"
using navigationButtons calling relevant `prepareForSegue` and `UnwindToSeque` methods, I am up-to-date with xcode version and using "ARC".

My problem is app launches fine. its loads "monthArray", not "grossMutableArray" (was hoping it would load 0000.00 objects). Once I navigate to "AddHoursViewController.h"(third in stack) and try to come back (`unwindToSegue` called which calls `[dataModel saveDataToDisk];` app crashes. if I comment `[dataModel saveDataToDisk];` method out, app navigates fine without loading any data.

Interesting thing is after "reseting iOS simulator and deleting all simulator data" if I comment out `self.grossPayArray = [rootObject objectForKey:kGrossPayArrayKey];` in `-(void)loadDataFromDisk` before launch, app launches than --> stop simulator --> remove comment --> relaunch again and everything works fine.

I have tried all sorts of things after doing Google, nothing seems to work for me. I think `init` method needs amendment but I cannot get my head round to it, please help.

**Relevant codes** and **Crash log**:

```
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailsViewController.h"
#import "AddHoursViewController.h"
NSString *const kMonthArrayKey = @"MonthArray";
NSString *const kGrossPayArrayKey = @"GrossPayArray";
NSUInteger indexNumber;
ViewController *viewController;

@implementation DataModel
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
self.monthArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apr", @"May", @"Jun", @"Jul", @"Aug", @"Sep", @"Oct", @"Nov", @"Dec", @"Jan", @"Feb", @"Mar", nil];

self.grossPayArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", @"0000.00", nil];

[self loadDataFromDisk];
        //NSLog(@"init method called");     
    }
    return self;
}

//NSCODING
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.monthArray forKey:kMonthArrayKey];
[encoder encodeObject:self.grossPayArray forKey:kGrossPayArrayKey];

    NSLog(@"-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder method called");
}

//decoding data from file
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self){

        return nil;
}

self.grossPayArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kGrossPayArrayKey];
        return self;
}   


#pragma mark Methods associated with saving data on the disk for this class
//file path where data resides
-(NSString*)pathForDataFile
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *pathToDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileFolder = [pathToDirectory objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = @"MyAppfileName";
    if ( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileFolder] == NO)
    {
       // NSLog(@"pathForDataFile does not exist %@", filePath);
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:fileFolder withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@ documentDirectory", fileName);
    }

return [fileFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}

//Method to save data
-(void)saveDataToDisk
{
    NSString *path = [self pathForDataFile];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSUInteger indexNumber = [defaults integerForKey:@"Index number"];

    self.rootObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];//dictionary creation


    [self.grossPayArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexNumber withObject:basicPayString];

    [self.rootObject setObject:[self grossPayArray] forKey:kGrossPayArrayKey];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.rootObject toFile:path];}

//method to load data
- (void)loadDataFromDisk
//comment out eg grossArray array, loads it from -init, after first launch and invoking (self saveDataToDisk] --> stop app --> remove double slashed --> relaunch,  will than replace object at index
//putting arrays under this code replaces object at index for chosen month and keeps one added before. if remove array from here replaces object at index but puts values from init methods in other objects.
    {
    NSString *path = [self pathForDataFile];
    //NSLog(@"path in loadDataFromDisk %@", path);
    NSDictionary *rootObject;
    rootObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

    self.grossPayArray = [rootObject objectForKey:kGrossPayArrayKey];   
}



-(id)initWithDocPath:(NSString *)docPath
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        _docPath = [docPath copy];
}
    _docPath = [self pathForDataFile];
    //NSLog(@"doc path init %@", _docPath);
    return self;

}

@end
```

/////////////////Error log/crash log when unwind to segue called which calls [dataModel saveDataToDisk]; if call to saveDataToDisk commented out than app navigates OK without loading any data./////////

```
2014-05-26 15:25:27.596 CollectionFromNSObject[1179:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: grossPayArray)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x018de1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0165d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01967eb8 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 888
    3   CollectionFromNSObject              0x0000868f -[DataModel saveDataToDisk] + 2927
    4   CollectionFromNSObject              0x00063b13 -[DetailsViewController unwindToDetailsViewController:] + 19203
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0166f82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    6   UIKit                               0x009f6a91 -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] + 536
    7   UIKit                               0x00881f87 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0166f880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    9   UIKit                               0x0031f3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    10  UIKit                               0x0060c8df -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
Continues...................
```

Comment: Well its saying `setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil`, so check the argument and see if its ever `nil`, and debug from there. Good job on providing code and crash logs!

Comment: The reason couldn't be better explained on here than Xcode is already doing: "setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: basicPayArray)"

Comment: Key: basicPayArray is another array. I deleted because its same. So you can safely read it as Key:grossPayArray. True but what happens when I comment out array on first launch that kicks off subsequent launches OK.

Comment: I am looking for suggestion in my code. As I cannot get my head round to launching array from -(id)init when app is very first time launched and than start replacing/saving data in the same NSMutableArray(grossArray) when app is launched and user generate data.

Comment: For future reference editing your earlier question would have been better than posting a new one. It would still bump it to the front page.

Comment: UPDATE: if I do data.grossArray = [[NSMurableArray alloc]init]. I get out bound error.

Comment: dataModel.grossArray = [NSMutableArray arrayawithObjects:@"1",@"2",....nil]; replaced object at given index and keeps other value. What's the solution please.

Comment: `self.monthArray = [decoder decodeObject];` -- Shouldn't you be using a key here??

Comment: That's part works. I just want a suggestion on once app is launched and start saving data. It should replace objects in mutable arrays which are saved on file under rootobject. At the moment it replaces only last object and reset other objects to init method objects.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your dictionary needs to be written to the disk before you can grab it from the disk.

There are lots of issues otherwise, but there is your crux. I believe you will pick up good habits over time, so I'll ignore the rest. Try to find a mentor and separate out the responsibilities. Eg, saving, loading, viewing are different parts

Comment: You mean they saving, loading and viewing should be in different classes. ?

Comment: What [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.rootObject toFile:path]; for? My understanding is calling this method saves rootobject to path. And that rootobject has all mutableArrays.